# SQL Oracle - show data only for 15th day before today

Tags: oracle, datetime

I'm trying to get the data but only for one day - 15th day before today. It needs to be dynamic, so for example when I run a query today, I should get the results for 11th June, tomorrow for 12th June etc...

I use the below line to get the data for the previous day:

`bo.status_dt BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)  AND TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1/86400)`

I tried to modify my statement as follows but no luck:

`bo.STATUS_DT > TRUNC(SYSDATE -15) and bo.STATUS_DT < SYSDATE +14`

or

`bo.status_dt = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 15)`

I'm quite new to Oracle and not 100% sure how to modify my statement to get the required data. Cheers in advance.

Comment: What does "but no luck" mean - did you get an error, no data, or more data than you wanted?

Comment: I had no error in both cases. When I run ```bo.status_dt = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 15``` statement, I had no data. When I tried to run the other one - ```bo.STATUS_DT > TRUNC(SYSDATE -15) and bo.STATUS_DT < SYSDATE +14``` it was running for over an hour but couldn't finish. I'm guessing it tried to get the data for more than one day as usually it takes me around 15 minutes to retrieve the data for the previous day from the database.

Comment: Yes, it will be attempting to pull 15 (and a bit) days of data at once, assuming the status date isn't ever set to a future date/time. You need -14, not +14, but need to trunc that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt with

```
bo.STATUS_DT > TRUNC(SYSDATE -15) and bo.STATUS_DT < SYSDATE +14
```

should get *more* data than you want:

```
select sysdate, TRUNC(SYSDATE - 15), SYSDATE + 14
from dual;

SYSDATE             TRUNC(SYSDATE-15)   SYSDATE+14         
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2020-06-26 11:41:29 2020-06-11 00:00:00 2020-07-10 11:41:29
```

So you'll get everything *after* (but not including) 2020-06-11 00:00:00, and before 2020-07-10 11:39:33.

You probably want:

```
bo.STATUS_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -15) and bo.STATUS_DT < TRUNC(SYSDATE -14)
```

i.e. *minus* fourteen days; and using `>=` instead of `>` to include exactly midnight:

```
select sysdate, TRUNC(SYSDATE - 15), TRUNC(SYSDATE - 14)
from dual;

SYSDATE             TRUNC(SYSDATE-15)   TRUNC(SYSDATE-14)  
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2020-06-26 11:41:29 2020-06-11 00:00:00 2020-06-12 00:00:00
```

So you'll get everything at or after (and including) 2020-06-11 00:00:00, and before 2020-06-12 00:00:00 - which is that complete day.

---

Using

```
bo.status_dt = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 15)
```

would only give you data at exactly 2020-06-11 00:00:00, with nothing from the rest of that day. Quite possible there would be no matching rows. You might be tempted, then, to do:

```
TRUNC(bo.status_dt) = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 15)
```

which would indeed cover the whole day; but applying the trunc (or any) function to the table column value will prevent a normal index on that column being used. You could have a function-based index, but if it's already indexed then there's no benefit to doing that instead of using the full-day range.

Comment: ```bo.STATUS_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -15) and bo.STATUS_DT < TRUNC(SYSDATE -14)``` works like a charm, cheers Alex. Thanks also for explaining the logic around it, makes perfect sense now and I know where the mistake was made.

Answer (score 2):

`DATE` values in Oracle **always** include the time part, even when it is not **displayed** by default.

Try

```
SELECT 
   TO_CHAR(bo.status_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE -1), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1/86400), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE -15), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
   TO_CHAR(SYSDATE +14, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

then it should be clear where the mistake is. Since you don't provide any sample data it is difficult to offer a ready-to-use solution.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried Domscheit. I'm running a query now, I'll share the output